# Intellij ApplicationContext errors being incorrectly highlighted

Tags: spring, intellij-idea

- 1) cannot resolve directory javascript
- 2) attribute    p:cache-manager-ref not allowed here
- 3) cannot  resolve symbol    datasource

All shown in red below :
[image: intellij code inspection errors]

1) because my app context is in src/main/resources and gets copied to WEB-INF, so I how can I reference resources, by moving appContext.xml to WEB-INF ?

2) Intellij can't use p namespce as it does not require xsd ? But I have declared the namespace correctly - it validates in netbeans.

3) Don't know

Btw, these do not effect the correct running of my app. It works, and no errors are displayed in eclipse or netbeans.

Here is my artfiact set-up, the javascript and images directory are within webapp:
[image]

In fact if I try t manually add the resource directories to deployment I am prompted with he message it is a duplicate:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You need to configure a web artifact for your module to let IDEA know about your application layout. 
2) You need to declare p-namespace, like xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
3) It seems your library does not contain debugger information. I'd suggest to use type="javax.sql.DataSource" here.

Comment: I have configured a web artifact, see edit... and I have declared the p namespace, but not been able to register it as there is no asscoiated xsd. Type info - where would I add that ?

Comment: You need to add an instruction to the artifact that copies /main/resources to /WEB-INF. They are copied to /WEB-INF/classes by default, that's why IDEA can't catch it. BTW, how do you configure maven to make it copy your resources? Maven instructions should be recognized by IDEA and imported into artifacts.

Comment: This works for me: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager" p:cacheManager-ref="foo"/>

</beans>

Comment: I tried manually adding the resrouce directories to web deployment artifact, however I got duplicate directory message, see edit. And the p namescpae has been declared, it works and validates everywhere else. My library does nto contain debugger information  - huh ? And javax.sql.Datasource I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: Ah yes changing to p:configLocation and p:cacheManager fixed 2, thanks. But I still have a problem with 1 and 3 :-(

Comment: You need to replace your library jar file with one compiled with debugging info option. Once again, selecting argument by type is preferred, because it works with any jar.

Comment: Ah, OK, I got ya. Yes thats 3 fixed too :-) Only problem left is mvc resources directory ? I just use the maven war plugin and the defaults. A maven install works as expected.#

Comment: You need to add your /main/resources directory to your artifact.

Comment: the content gets copied to WEB-INF classes, that works fine. I have added src/main/resources to artifact. But that does not remove the highlighted error when I map static resources (javascript, images)  in applicationContext.xml. I also tried adding the "images" and "javascript" directories manually but I got the message in edit.

Comment: Yes it is not fixed. Is it your case?

Comment: My case in youtrack ? No. I have replicated it, it seems.